# python oneline to create matrix of given order

Tags: python, matrix

I am looking for python oneliner that will create matrix with the given order and fill values from 1 to n. n = r X c

I achieved till this,

```
Matrix1 = [[x+1 for x in range(rowCount)] for x in range(columnCount)]
print Matrix1
```

But the output is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I'm just curious... why put the constraint of a one liner?

Comment: i just want to know is this possible with one line!

Comment: I just find this whole goal of finding a one liner for everything very pedantic and not really worthwhile of the effort.

Comment: oops.. am just looking to reduce my code.. i write more than 25 lines for this :(

Comment: One of the primary goals with python code is to make it readable.  Creating very long one liners steps away from the goal.  Sometimes it's a necessary evil, but I find the practice of trying to find a way to put a lot of steps into a single line of code rather a waste of time and effort.  But that's just my opinion

Comment: agree.. i won't ignore your advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> matrix1 = [[1+x+y*rowCount for x in range(rowCount)] for y in range(columnCount)]
>>> matrix1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: When I put row count = 10, and column count = 3, it gives me:


`In [29]: [[1+x+y*r for x in range(r)] for y in range(c)]

Out[29]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]`

Shouldn't I be getting 10 rows, instead of 3?

Comment: You _are_ getting ten rows... If you interpret the results as column-major and not row-major. If you want the latter, you can do `[[1+x+y*columnCount for x in range(columnCount)] for y in range(rowCount)]`

Answer (score 2):

No, the correct way is without loop (and in one line):

```
import numpy as np

rowCount = 2
colCount = 5

np.array(range(1, 1+rowCount*colCount)).reshape(rowCount,colCount)

#array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: up for "without loop" solution

Comment: this is great solution, but also am looking for  a way without any modules :(

Comment: unfortunately you should really use numpy for dealing with matrix!

Answer (score 1):

You use the same variable for your two loops. Try this :

```
matrix1 = [[y*rowCount + x + 1 for x in range(rowCount)] for y in range(columnCount)]
print matrix1
```

Comment: That produces `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4]]` rather than the desired `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Given `c` (column count), `n`, here's what I came up with:

```
[range(0, n)[cx:cx+c] for cx in range(0, n, c)]
```

Result:

```
In [16]: n = 9

In [17]: c = 3

In [18]: [range(0, n)[cx:cx+c] for cx in range(0, n, c)]
Out[18]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

EDIT: More examples for non square matrices:
(`mod` is a function i created to quickly change `r` and `c` values, and calculate `n` from them)

```
In [23]: mod(8, 2)  # 8 rows, 2 columns

In [24]: [range(0, n)[cx:cx+c] for cx in range(0, n, c)]
Out[24]: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]]

In [25]: mod(3, 6)  # 3 rows, 6 columns

In [26]: [range(0, n)[cx:cx+c] for cx in range(0, n, c)]
Out[26]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]

In [27]: mod(10, 3)  # 10 rows, 3 columns

In [28]: [range(0, n)[cx:cx+c] for cx in range(0, n, c)]
Out[28]: 
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17],
 [18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23],
 [24, 25, 26],
 [27, 28, 29]]
```

It works for them too.

Comment: @karthikeayan It works equally well for non square matrices too. See my updated answer with such examples. Meanwhile, for a `rowCount=10`, and `columnCount = 3`, the chosen answer doesn't give the right answer. It gives this: `In [29]: [[1+x+y*r for x in range(r)] for y in range(c)]Out[29]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]`